# Conditional menu for registerd users/guests (Genesis framework)

Tags: user-access, genesis-theme-framework, members

I'm running Genesis Framework on WordPress and I have to display a different top menu for logged in users and a different one for unregistered users (guests).

I created the 2 menus in the WP backend > Appearance > Menus:

- `top-menu1` for `guests`
- `top-menu2` for `registered users`

Normally I'd have to just use this:

```
if( !is_user_logged_in() ){
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'primary' => 'top-menu1' ) );
} else {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'primary' => 'top-menu2' ) );
}
```

Since this is Genesis though, I'd like you to point me to:

- what's the equivalent of the `wp_nav_menu` function?
- how do I register the 2 menus?
- what files do I have to modify?

Comment: Close-voted as **too localized**. As Genesis is a commercial Theme, we don't have access to the code to be able to help provide an answer. Have you tried **[StudioPress support](http://www.studiopress.com/support/forumdisplay.php?f=69)**?